# Declare an array of objects in php

Tags: php

How can I declare a list of objects in php as a private instance variable?

In Java the declaration would look something like this
 `private ArrayList<Object> ls` 
and the constructor would have this
`ls = new ArrayList<Object>();`

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP allocates memory dynamically and what's more, it doesn't care what sort of object you store in your array.

If you want to declare your array before you use it something along these lines would work:

```
var $myArray = array();
```

Then you can store any object you like in your variable $myArray. Many people find this a strange concept to grasp after working in a strict language like java.

Comment: What is the difference between var $myArray = array() and $array = array()

Comment: there is no difference, that's only name of that variable, you can use whatever you want :) it's like `ls` in your question

Comment: I meant whether I use 'var' or not before the variable.

Comment: @user1114 it's deprecated way to declare class variables (used in PHP 4), in PHP 5 you should use public/private..

Answer (score 1):

you can declare it in class like

```
private $array = array();
```

and append objects (or anything) to that array like

```
$array[] = some object
```

Comment: You can also use it associatively, by saying `$array['key'] = value;`