# Can I define array of enums parameter in function declaration?

Tags: php, laravel

I laravel 9 I have installed
"bensampo/laravel-enum": "^5.2" and created new enum with command
php artisan make:enum SearchDataType

and I wonder if there is a way to describe function with array of SearchDataType elements, like :

```
public function searchSiteContent(string $s = '', bool $partial= false, SearchDataType array $searchDataTypes= []) : array;
```

In line above I got syntax error, untill I remove SearchDataType in $searchDataTypes declarations

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PHP allocates memory dynamically and what's more, `it doesn't care what sort of object you store in your array`. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759118/7703556

So you can do this check inside your function.
By using `array_map` or `array_walk`
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46035743/7703556

In your case for example with `array_map` :

```
 function isInstanceOfSearchDataType($variable) {
    if(!($variable instanceof SearchDataType)) {
      throw new Exception('Variable is not instance of SearchDataType');
    }
}

public function searchSiteContent(string $s = '', bool $partial= false, $searchDataTypes= []) : array {
    array_map(isInstanceOfSearchDataType, $searchDataTypes); // do this at the beginning
  // ... code

  return $someArray;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
public function searchSiteContent(string $s = '', bool $partial= false, SearchDataType ...$searchDataTypes) : array;
```

Note the 3 dots before $searchDataType. This will be an array when you use it.

much simpler then having a lot of code just to validate input.